# Dynamically resize controls based on drag area

Tags: delphi, resize, anchor

I have a form with a TTreeview on the left and a TGroupbox on the right. When the form is resized by dragging on the right edge, I want the Groupbox to grow or shrink accordingly. When the form is dragged on the left I want the Treeview to resize. I tried the code below and right resizing works fine. But left resizing causes the treeview to grow longer than it should. What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPoint;
begin
  P:= ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  if(P.X<0) then begin
    Treeview1.Anchors:= [akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom];
    Groupbox1.Anchors:= [akTop,akBottom];
  end
  else begin
    Treeview1.Anchors:= [akLeft,akTop,akBottom];
    Groupbox1.Anchors:= [akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom];
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than handling the `OnResize` event, you can instead intercept the [`WM_SIZING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647.aspx) message instead

> Sent to a window that the user is resizing. **By processing this message, an application can monitor the size and position of the drag rectangle** and, if needed, change its size or position.

Its `wParam` value tells you exactly which edge(s) of the window are being resized.  You can use that to adjust the `Anchors` accordingly, eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMSizing(var Message: TMessage); message WM_SIZING;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.WMSizing(var Message: TMessage);
var
  TreeViewAnchors: TAnchors;
  GroupBoxAnchors: TAnchors;
begin
  inherited;

  TreeViewAnchors := [akTop, akBottom];
  GroupBoxAnchors := [akTop, akBottom];

  case Message.WParam of
    WMSZ_LEFT, WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT, WMSZ_TOPLEFT: begin
      TreeViewAnchors := TreeViewAnchors + [akLeft, akRight];
      GroupBoxAnchors := GroupBoxAnchors + [akRight];
    end;
    WMSZ_RIGHT, WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT, WMSZ_TOPRIGHT: begin
      TreeViewAnchors := TreeViewAnchors + [akLeft];
      GroupBoxAnchors := GroupBoxAnchors + [akLeft, akRight];
    end;
  end;

  TreeView1.Anchors := TreeViewAnchors;
  GroupBox1.Anchors := GroupBoxAnchors;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to anchor to the right the Groupbox when you resize the window on the left.

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPoint;
begin
  if GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) and $8000 <> 0 then exit;
  P:= ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  if(P.X<0) then begin
    Treeview1.Anchors:= [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
    Groupbox1.Anchors:= [akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  end
  else begin
    Treeview1.Anchors:= [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
    Groupbox1.Anchors:= [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  end;
end;
```

I tried it and it seems to do what you want to do

**EDIT :**

You can also use *Align* property (be careful on the order, component with 'alClient' value at the end) :

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPoint;
begin
  if GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) and $8000 <> 0 then exit;
  P:= ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  if(P.X<0) then begin        
    Groupbox1.Align:= alRight;
    Treeview1.Align:= alClient;
  end
  else begin
    Treeview1.Align:= alLeft;
    Groupbox1.Align:= alClient;
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT 2 : check the state of the left button of the mouse**

You can check the state of a button or a key with the function GetAsyncKeyState(vKey) of the Winapi.
It returns state of the button in SmallInt with bit 15 0/1 if the button has been pressed or not.

[GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293.aspx)

Comment: No, when you drag on the left side to the left and right several times the Groupbox eventually disappears. There is something odd happening here.

Comment: @fullerm Adding `akRight` to `GroupBox1.Anchors` seems to work fine in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. If it doesn't work for you, there must be something else in your test case that you did not tell us.

Comment: I'm using XE and tested this code in a blank project. After much back and forth dragging on the left side, the Treeview overlaps onto the Groupbox. Maybe there is a bug in XE.

Comment: I saw the problem : when you resize the window on the left side and you drag your cursor over the right side of your window, then the Treeview overlaps onto the Groupbox because I think the OnResize event is handled again with the P.X > 0. We have to find an other solution...

Comment: I found a solution : you can check the state of the left button of the mouse. If it is clicked, exit the procedure, else do the stuff. To check the state of a button or a key : GetAsyncKeyState(vKey) --> Winapi.Windows

Comment: If using GetAsyncKeyState, the procedure will never fire when resizing the form with the mouse though.